# 'com.facebook.react.bridge.ObjectAlreadyConsumedException' exception

Tags: android, react-native

I have the following method:

```
 public void onTap(ReadableMap item) {
            WritableMap eventMap = Arguments.createMap();
            eventMap.merge(item);
            mEventEmitter.receiveEvent(getId(), "onItemSelect", eventMap);
}
```

I get the exception:

> Method threw
>   'com.facebook.react.bridge.ObjectAlreadyConsumedException' exception.
>   Cannot evaluate com.facebook.react.bridge.WritableNativeMap.toString()

It is really strange since the eventMap seems to be properly constructed.
Can someone please help?
What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you

Comment: Getting the same error. Did you find any solution?